# Is org.joda.time.DateTimeFormat thread safe?

Tags: scala, concurrency, jodatime

I have an instance of an org.joda.time.DateTimeFormat in an object :

```
   object TimeRange {
    lazy val dateFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYY-MM-dd")
   }
```

My API is asynchronous (using Finagle Future) and different threads may want to access my dateFormat to format date using function dateFormat.parseDateTime("2013-07-01"). My question is: how can I be sure that this method invocation will be thread safe ? Can we assume that all method invocations without side effects are thread safe ? Does it depend on the specific implementation of DateTimeFormat ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [the doc](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html):

> DateTimeFormat is thread-safe and immutable, and the formatters it
>   returns are as well.